# Units of measurement conversion database

Tags: data-request

Tools to convert units of measurement and conversion data is abundant, but what databases/datasets exist which aim to consolidate unit conversion data?

For example:

> 1 pound equals 0.45359237 kilogram per ["Refinement Of Values For The Yard And The Pound", US Nat Bureau of Standards, 1959](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/FedRegister/FRdoc59-5442.pdf)

Ideally it should:

- indicate which coefficients are prescribed by standards (rather than derived from the application of multiple other coefficients)
- cite the standard for each conversion coefficient
- carefully indicated precision of conversion coefficients
- contain standard unit abbreviations/symbology
- document units clearly to avoid confusion (ex: aliases and formal names)
- be expressed/published in a portable machine-readable format (i.e. JSON)

Fantastically it would:

- also contain outdated standard historical values
- contain symbology for hybrid units
- describe context in which particular units are used (professions, regions of the world, etc.)
- cite standards for the unit symbology (ex: "lb")

This would make implementing a unit conversion library much easier since the step of aggregating conversion coefficients would be unnecessary.

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement your own unit conversion library, when [`udunits`](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/) and similar libraries already exist?

Comment: I don't want to; that's why I'm asking the question :-)  I'm more interested in the quality of the unit conversion dataset rather than tools themselves.  One of the issues with similar libraries is incomplete data and lack of verification of / references for the contained data.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I'm not quite sure what you're asking for.  A meta-database that describes the quality of other databases?

Comment: By references I mean that sources for the data contained in the database are explicitly cited.  The fact that UCAR maintains that tool offers evidence to its validity; it suggests that it is carefully maintained / endorsed.  Many tools are maintained by an individual and only contain coefficients (which may have been copy-pasted and may or may not be expressed to appropriate precision).  The presence of references indicates an academic diligence and offers a mechanism for verification.  The best database that exists may likely be embedded in a tool like `udunits`; it needn't be stand-alone.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [database](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-current/doc/udunits/udunits2.html) that comes with the [`udunits`](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/) library, on which many other unit conversion libraries rely.  For example, see [SI derived units](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-current/udunits/udunits2-derived.xml) and [non-SI units](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-current/udunits/udunits2-common.xml).  `udunits` is developed by the University Corporation for Atmospheric Research (UCAR).  Its [license](https://github.com/Unidata/UDUNITS-2/blob/master/COPYRIGHT) appears quite open to me.

See also the [`udunits` github page](https://github.com/Unidata/UDUNITS-2).

---

P.S. I don't know why you would want to implement your own units conversion library when `udunits` already exists.